# How to write Spark dataframe output as parquet output in Azure Machine Learning?

Tags: python, pyspark, azure-machine-learning-service

I am moving my Databricks code to Azure ML, however, I was not able to find a way to migrate it to write output as parquet output to the data lake.

I have tried the following ways but nothing works; there's one way from Azure ML documentation which I found, but that's still in experimental phase and I don't want to risk on that. Any suggestions?

```
output_directory = "prediction"
output_path = f"/{output_directory}/test/.parquet" 

#write_df = dummy.write.mode("overwrite").parquet(output_path)
#write_df = dummy.write.parquet(output_path, mode="overwrite")
#write_df = dummy.write.to_parquet_files(output_path)
```

I have added the error log here

```js
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o428.parquet. : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted. at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.jobAbortedError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:651) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:278) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:186) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:113) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:111) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.executeCollect(commands.scala:125) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$1(QueryExecution.scala:98) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$6(SQLExecution.scala:109) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:169) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:95) at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:779) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:98) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$$anonfun$eagerlyExecuteCommands$1.applyOrElse(QueryExecution.scala:94) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$1(TreeNode.scala:584) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:176) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:584) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:267) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.transformDownWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:263) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:30) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDown(TreeNode.scala:560) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.eagerlyExecuteCommands(QueryExecution.scala:94) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:81) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.commandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:79) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertCommandExecuted(QueryExecution.scala:116) at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:860) at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:390) at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveInternal(DataFrameWriter.scala:363) at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:239) at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.parquet(DataFrameWriter.scala:793) at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244) at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357) at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282) at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132) at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79) at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182) at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106) at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 93.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 93.0 (TID 44) (10.178.60.11 executor driver): java.io.IOException: Mkdirs failed to create file:/test/.parquet/_temporary/0/_temporary/attempt_202305161243531956885195474531830_0093_m_000000_44 (exists=false, cwd=file:/mnt/batch/tasks/shared/LS_root/mounts/clusters/az01aml0410/code/Users/) at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:515) at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:500) at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:1195) at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:1175) at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.util.HadoopOutputFile.create(HadoopOutputFile.java:74) at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileWriter.<init>(ParquetFileWriter.java:329) at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:482) at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:420) at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:409) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetOutputWriter.<init>(ParquetOutputWriter.scala:36) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$$anon$1.newInstance(ParquetFileFormat.scala:155) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SingleDirectoryDataWriter.newOutputWriter(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:161) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SingleDirectoryDataWriter.<init>(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:146) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:317) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$write$21(FileFormatWriter.scala:256) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:136) at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548) at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1504) at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) Driver stacktrace: at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2672) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2608) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2607) at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62) at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55) at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2607) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1182) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1182) at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1182) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2860) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2802) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2791) at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:952) at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2228) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:245) ... 42 more Caused by: java.io.IOException: Mkdirs failed to create file:/test/.parquet/_temporary/0/_temporary/attempt_202305161243531956885195474531830_0093_m_000000_44 (exists=false, cwd=file:/mnt/batch/tasks/shared/LS_root/mounts/clusters/az01aml0410/code/Users/) at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:515) at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:500) at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:1195) at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:1175) at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.util.HadoopOutputFile.create(HadoopOutputFile.java:74) at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileWriter.<init>(ParquetFileWriter.java:329) at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:482) at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:420) at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:409) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetOutputWriter.<init>(ParquetOutputWriter.scala:36) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$$anon$1.newInstance(ParquetFileFormat.scala:155) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SingleDirectoryDataWriter.newOutputWriter(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:161) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SingleDirectoryDataWriter.<init>(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:146) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:317) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$write$21(FileFormatWriter.scala:256) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:136) at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548) at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1504) at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ... 1 more
```

there was lot other stuff like the log i pasted,but this was the only piece i could understand something from one of the other runs

```js
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 31 in stage 27.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 31.0 in stage 27.0 (TID 1246) (10.178.60.11 executor driver): java.io.IOException: Mkdirs failed to create file:/test.parquet/_temporary/0/_temporary/attempt_202305151258146556003709353834404_0027_m_000031_1246 (exists=false, cwd=file:/mnt/batch/tasks/shared/LS_root/mounts/clusters/abcskbd/code/Users/)
```

Comment: what is the error you getting?

Comment: @JayashankarGS  lot of java and spark errors , i wasn't able to understand the whole log

Comment: @JayashankarGS i have added the log in the question fyr

Comment: Where you are running this code. is it in Azure ml workspace notebook?

Comment: yes, also as python script in my workspace, tried both @JayashankarGS

Comment: adding other snippet as well, kindly look :) @JayashankarGS

Comment: which compute instance you are using to run notebook? is it serverless spark compute.

Comment: its the Standard_DS1_v2 (1 cores, 3.5 GB RAM, 7 GB disk) one @JayashankarGS

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
import os
abspath = "file://"+os.path.abspath(".")
output_directory = "prediction"
output_path = f"/{output_directory}/test/res.parquet"
path = abspath+output_path
df.write.mode("overwrite").parquet(path)
```

[image]

And this is the output after reading the file.

[image]

Comment: kindly see the question again, thats what i tried

Comment: Yes.What you tried to write parquet is correct but the path you are gave, creating this error `Mkdirs failed to create file:/test/.parquet/_temporary/0/_temporary/`. So i given the code above to get the path and write the the parquet.

Comment: but this writes to the local workspace not the datalake right?
i'm looking for options to write to datalake

Comment: Please mention which format you want. Is it `delta` or  `parquet` format you want?